# C# Регулярное выражение не работает после переноса

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Помогите понять почему регулярка прекрасно отрабатывает на сайте, но не работает в проекте. Причем даже если использовать код генератор с сайта в нем она тоже не хочет работать.
https://regex101.com/r/Ed8JIJ/1

Comment: Все данные для формирования ответа должны быть прямо в вопросе, а не по ссылкам на сторонние сайты. Ссылки не вечные и ваш вопрос сразу потеряет смысл после того как ссылка перестанет работать.

Answer (score 0):

В C# рабочая регулярка приобрела такой вид:

```
string pattern = "Settings\\s\\{.\\n.+?.\\}.\\n\\b";
```

Comment: `@"Settings\s\{.\n.+?.\}.\n\b";` - можно использовать verbatim string.